# Angular2 auth token in header request CORS/Preflight issue

Tags: apache, rest, angular, cors, wamp

I'm trying to request a `HTTP GET` call to my local REST REST `http://demosite.com/mage_auth/api/rest` it needs an authorization token to let a user call an endpoint.

So in my request I passed `headers.set('Authorization', token)` and content-type JSON, however it doesn't seems to be passing the header in the Request's Header when I check the network response.

I've created a httpClient Service to pass the auth token: --

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
 var sample3Results = (new OAuthSimple()).sign({
  path: 'http://www.demosites.com/mage_auth/',
  signatures: {
    'consumer_key': key,
    'shared_secret': secret,
    'access_token': token,
    'access_secret': tokensecret
  }
 });
 try {
  console.debug('Sample 3', sample3Results);
 } catch (e) { };

 let headerAuth = sample3Results.header;
 headers.set('Authorization', headerAuth);
 headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
}

get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
```

My component request look like this: --

```
this.httClient.get('http://www.demosites.com/mage_auth/api/rest/products')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data: ', data);
  })
```

The REST API is running on WAMP server, so I've also added some CORS values in `httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, content-type"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

And I'm still getting this Error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.demosites.com/mage_auth/api/rest/products. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

Just in case, I also added a proxy.config.json from `Angular-cli` as thought that'd fix it because the request is coming from `localhost:4200`. But seems wasn't the case, I'm out of idea why it still giving a preflight error.

Can someone point out what's wrong with this request?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so, could you share your solution? For I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

That can be a misconfiguration of the CORS filter server side.
As for me, even if my CORS filter was well configured server side, I still faced the same issue. I used the `RequestOptions` of Angular for the headers. This is how I soved it within my angular service

**Angular 2**

```js
header.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        header.append("X-Auth-Token", token);
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header})
        return this.http.get(url,  options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

**Angular 4.3**

- Define an interceptor

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AppService} from '../app.service';
@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        token: `Bearer token`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

`HttpRequests` are immutable objects. So we need to copy them and then modidfy the copy.

- Import the interceptor in `app.module.ts`

```js
 ...
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: Interceptor, multi: true},
    AppService
  ...
   ]
```

- Use the interceptor in `app.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
  connectServer() {

    return this.http.get('url')
      .map(response => response);
  }
}
```